# AUTOSAR configuaration - DCM module

Tags: embedded, diagnostics, autosar

I am stuck at a point where I am configuring the DCM module and the current parameter I am trying to configure `DcmTimStrP2AdjustServer`,

The requirement is `P2CAN_SERVER_MAX = 25ms;` `P2STARCAN_SERVER_MAX = 5000ms;`

Is `DcmDspSessionP2ServerMax` the same as `P2CAN_SERVER_MAX`? and if it is the same
What is the need for `DcmTimStrP2AdjustServer` and how do I find the best value for `DcmTimStrP2AdjustServer`.(The values all should be a multiple of `DcmTaskTime` which I find to be logical).

```
DcmTaskTime = 5ms;
```

I am following Autosar 4.0.3, using ETAS tool for configuring the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjust value is an internal value, in order to adjust the delay between the Dcm Transmit Request and the message being actually on the Bus.

The definition of P2ServerMax and P2*ServerMax and their corresponding Adjust values is the same:

*This parameter is used to guarantee that the diagnostic response is available on the bus before reaching P2 by adjusting the current DcmDspSessionP2ServerMax. This parameter mainly represents the software architecture dependent communication delay between the time the transmission is initiated by DCM and the time when the message is actually transmitted to the bus*

Answer (score 2):

To fulfill your requirement, you need to configure respectively
`DcmDspSessionP2ServerMax` & `DcmDspSessionP2StarServerMax` for each session control in the `DcmDspSessionRows` at `Dcm/DcmConfigSet/DcmDsp/DcmDspSession/`.
i.e.

```
DcmDspSessionP2ServerMax 25
DcmDspSessionP2StarServerMax 5000
```

There is no `DcmTimStrP2AdjustServer`, but I guess you're referring to `DcmTimStrP2ServerAdjust` instead. `DcmTimStrP2ServerAdjust` & `DcmTimStrP2StarServerAdjust` should be configured to a multiple of your `DcmTaskTime` (5ms in your case, so i.e. 5ms, 10ms, 15, ms, ... is applicable) and are used to safeguard that the response is available on the bus before triggering the P2 or P2* timeouts. In your case you may want to set these values to the same values as in the `DcmDspSessionRows` if there is no other specification given, because the chosen timeout values there are already multiples of your `DcmTaskTime`:

```
DcmTimStrP2ServerAdjust  25
DcmTimStrP2StarServerAdjust 5000
```

Comment: But what I had configured was DcmDspSessionP2ServerMax 35 and DcmTimStrP2ServerAdjust  10 so that servermax-serveradjust = 25. Is this correct or Am I missing something again?

Comment: @SivaramakrishnaShriraam How did you came up with the formula `DcmDspSessionP2ServerMax - DcmTimStrP2ServerAdjust = P2CAN_SERVER_MAX`? That doesn't look right to me, you want to have the same timeout value except if `DcmDspSessionP2ServerMax` is not a multiple of your `DcmTaskTime`. The default value for `DcmTimStrP2ServerAdjust` is the same as `DcmDspSessionP2ServerMax`.

Comment: I could not configure the DcmTimStrP2ServerAdjust to 25, it(ETAS tool) said that the DcmDspSessionP2ServeMax - DcmTimStrP2ServerAdjust > DcmTaskTime.